# Finding best time from users usin JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I am trying to find the best result for each user from JSON.

```
const users = [
    {
        "key": "user1",
        "label": "Henry"
    },
    {
        "key": "user2",
        "label": "Michael"
    },
    {
        "key": "user3",
        "label": "Fiddel"
    },
    {
        "key": "user4",
        "label": "Alex"
    },
    {
        "key": "user5",
        "label": "Mark"
    }
]


const results = [
    {
        "user1": "00:31.241",
        "user2": "00:30.945",
        "user3": "00:33.065",
        "user4": null,
        "user5": null
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:28.963",
        "user2": "00:31.657",
        "user3": "00:28.504",
        "user4": null,
        "user5": null
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:26.956",
        "user2": "00:26.416",
        "user3": "00:27.328",
        "user4": "00:29.904",
        "user5": null
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:31.889",
        "user2": "00:32.739",
        "user3": "01:00.515",
        "user4": "00:28.336",
        "user5": "00:35.745"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:26.470",
        "user2": "00:30.063",
        "user3": "00:28.696",
        "user4": "00:30.248",
        "user5": "00:35.123"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:26.956",
        "user2": "00:33.588",
        "user3": "00:30.021",
        "user4": "00:29.154",
        "user5": "00:38.492"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:27.190",
        "user2": "00:32.307",
        "user3": "00:30.467",
        "user4": "00:30.189",
        "user5": "00:39.669"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:27.368",
        "user2": "00:28.124",
        "user3": "00:29.960",
        "user4": "00:29.649",
        "user5": "00:42.450"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:28.429",
        "user2": "00:27.651",
        "user3": "00:28.260",
        "user4": "00:30.077",
        "user5": "00:48.992"
    },
    {
        "user1": "00:29.425",
        "user2": "00:31.142",
        "user3": "00:40.343",
        "user4": "00:29.897",
        "user5": "00:42.552"
    }
]
```

So far I have came up with following solution:

```
let array = [];
 
const bestTime = results.map(Object.entries).flat().sort((a, b) => a[1] ?.localeCompare(b[1]))[0];

array = [users.filter(user => user.key === test[0])[0].label, test[1]]
```

Problem is that I can't figure out how to print out an array with the best result for each user instead of just one.
I would like to have an output like: [{name: 'Henry', value: 00:35.233}, {name: 'Michael', value: 00.27.333}, etc]

Now I am trying to get sum of all values for each user, I figured out how to filter out null values from JSON and how to get sum of all values. Problem is that results are string values and i cant figure out how to parse that data correctly to get sum.

```
const final = users.map(({ label, key }) => ({

    name: label,
    value: results.map(r => r[key]).filter(el => el != null).reduce((prev, curr) => parseInt(prev) + parseInt(prev);


}));
```

Answer (score 2):

First iterate over the `results` and combine each `user#` property value into an array for that user. Then you can sort it, create an object mapping `user#`s to names, and take the first value in the sorted array to get what you want:

```js
const users=[{key:"user1",label:"Henry"},{key:"user2",label:"Michael"},{key:"user3",label:"Fiddel"},{key:"user4",label:"Alex"},{key:"user5",label:"Inga"}],results=[{user1:"00:31.241",user2:"00:30.945",user3:"00:33.065",user4:null,user5:null},{user1:"00:28.963",user2:"00:31.657",user3:"00:28.504",user4:null,user5:null},{user1:"00:26.956",user2:"00:26.416",user3:"00:27.328",user4:"00:29.904",user5:null},{user1:"00:31.889",user2:"00:32.739",user3:"01:00.515",user4:"00:28.336",user5:"00:35.745"},{user1:"00:26.470",user2:"00:30.063",user3:"00:28.696",user4:"00:30.248",user5:"00:35.123"},{user1:"00:26.956",user2:"00:33.588",user3:"00:30.021",user4:"00:29.154",user5:"00:38.492"},{user1:"00:27.190",user2:"00:32.307",user3:"00:30.467",user4:"00:30.189",user5:"00:39.669"},{user1:"00:27.368",user2:"00:28.124",user3:"00:29.960",user4:"00:29.649",user5:"00:42.450"},{user1:"00:28.429",user2:"00:27.651",user3:"00:28.260",user4:"00:30.077",user5:"00:48.992"},{user1:"00:29.425",user2:"00:31.142",user3:"00:40.343",user4:"00:29.897",user5:"00:42.552"}];

const timesByUserNumber = {};
for (const result of results) {
  for (const [userNumber, time] of Object.entries(result)) {
    if (!timesByUserNumber[userNumber]) {
      timesByUserNumber[userNumber] = [];
    }
    if (time) {
      // Exclude nulls:
      timesByUserNumber[userNumber].push(time);
    }
  }
}
for (const arr of Object.values(timesByUserNumber)) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
}
const userLabelsByUserNumber = Object.fromEntries(
  users.map(({ key, label }) => [key, label])
);
const output = Object.entries(timesByUserNumber)
  .map(([userNumber, timeArr]) => ({
    name: userLabelsByUserNumber[userNumber],
    value: timeArr[0]
  }));
console.log(output);
```

You could also "sort" by comparing each item individually while iterating:

```js
const users=[{key:"user1",label:"Henry"},{key:"user2",label:"Michael"},{key:"user3",label:"Fiddel"},{key:"user4",label:"Alex"},{key:"user5",label:"Inga"}],results=[{user1:"00:31.241",user2:"00:30.945",user3:"00:33.065",user4:null,user5:null},{user1:"00:28.963",user2:"00:31.657",user3:"00:28.504",user4:null,user5:null},{user1:"00:26.956",user2:"00:26.416",user3:"00:27.328",user4:"00:29.904",user5:null},{user1:"00:31.889",user2:"00:32.739",user3:"01:00.515",user4:"00:28.336",user5:"00:35.745"},{user1:"00:26.470",user2:"00:30.063",user3:"00:28.696",user4:"00:30.248",user5:"00:35.123"},{user1:"00:26.956",user2:"00:33.588",user3:"00:30.021",user4:"00:29.154",user5:"00:38.492"},{user1:"00:27.190",user2:"00:32.307",user3:"00:30.467",user4:"00:30.189",user5:"00:39.669"},{user1:"00:27.368",user2:"00:28.124",user3:"00:29.960",user4:"00:29.649",user5:"00:42.450"},{user1:"00:28.429",user2:"00:27.651",user3:"00:28.260",user4:"00:30.077",user5:"00:48.992"},{user1:"00:29.425",user2:"00:31.142",user3:"00:40.343",user4:"00:29.897",user5:"00:42.552"}];

const userLabelsByUserNumber = Object.fromEntries(
  users.map(({ key, label }) => [key, label])
);
const grouped = {};
for (const result of results) {
  for (const [userNumber, time] of Object.entries(result)) {
    if (!time) continue;
    const name = userLabelsByUserNumber[userNumber];
    if (!grouped[name]) {
      grouped[name] = { name, value: time };
    } else if (grouped[name].value.localeCompare(time) > 0) {
      grouped[name].value = time;
    }
  }
}
console.log(Object.values(grouped));
```

Comment: Should we set [`{numeric: true}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Numeric_sorting) as a parameter to localeCompare

Comment: It's often a good idea, but given this format (##:##:###) it's not needed, because the numeric subsequences are always the same length, comparatively.

Answer (score 1):

I made out a solution by sorting the time values with [`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and getting the first element from the result array. But before using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `results` array and listing the times by its `key` properties inside an another `.map()` for each users.

See a working example below:

```js
const users = [{"key": "user1","label": "Henry"},{"key": "user2","label":"Michael"},{"key": "user3","label": "Fiddel"},{"key": "user4","label": "Alex"},{"key": "user5","label": "Inga"}]
const results = [{"user1": "00:31.241","user2": "00:30.945","user3": "00:33.065","user4": null,"user5": null},{"user1": "00:28.963","user2": "00:31.657","user3": "00:28.504","user4": null,"user5": null},{"user1": "00:26.956","user2": "00:26.416","user3": "00:27.328","user4": "00:29.904","user5": null},{"user1": "00:31.889","user2": "00:32.739","user3": "01:00.515","user4": "00:28.336","user5": "00:35.745"},{"user1": "00:26.470","user2": "00:30.063","user3": "00:28.696","user4": "00:30.248","user5": "00:35.123"},{"user1": "00:26.956","user2": "00:33.588","user3": "00:30.021","user4": "00:29.154","user5": "00:38.492"},{"user1": "00:27.190","user2": "00:32.307","user3": "00:30.467","user4": "00:30.189","user5": "00:39.669"},{"user1": "00:27.368","user2": "00:28.124","user3": "00:29.960","user4": "00:29.649","user5": "00:42.450"},{"user1": "00:28.429","user2": "00:27.651","user3": "00:28.260","user4": "00:30.077","user5": "00:48.992"},{"user1": "00:29.425","user2": "00:31.142","user3": "00:40.343","user4": "00:29.897","user5": "00:42.552"}]
    
const bestTimes = users.map(({label, key}) => ({
   name: label,
   value: results.map(r => r[key])
                 .sort((a, b) => 
                     a === null && b === null ?
                       -1 :
                       a.localeCompare(b))[0]
}))

console.log(bestTimes)
```